# Resources for learning about Word XML format?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

What resources would you recommend to learn about the Microsoft's Open Office format (the XML format introduced with Office 2007, not to be confused with OpenOffice.org), specifically for `.docx` Word files? (Ideally, ones with lots of samples and tutorials.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Top 10 List to Learn Open XML

1. Start with [Open XML Explained](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6f264d0b-23e8-43fe-9f82-9ab627e5eaa3&displaylang=en).
   This is an easy to read eBook on
   Open XML.
2. Next view with [WordProcessingML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/archive/category/1003.aspx)
   articles on OpenXMLDeveloper.org.
   They are quick and effective way to
   show you some of the ways people are
   doing different things.
3. Then go learn a bit more about [Open
   Packaging Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Packaging_Convention) - this is
   how Open XML files are packed
   (zipped) and the relationships the
   files in side the package have to
   each other. (XPS documents also use OPC format).
4. Now grab the [ISO/IEC 29500:2008
   spec](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_tc_browse.htm?commid=45374) and keep it handy - what
   exists in here is almost everything
   you need to know. You can also view
   the standard online at
   http://www.documentinteropinitiative.org/.
5. Supplement #4 with the [Office
   implementation guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee908654%28v=office.12%29.aspx) of the
   standard to see how values default to and are implemented in
   Word as opposed to other clients. Also, grab the [Word Extensions guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd773189%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to view how Word (specifically 2010) has added and implemented extensions to the standard.
6. Now start with the following blogs -
   they are amazing guides to the real
   power under the hood of Open XML: a)
   [Eric White's old blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite), b) [Eric
   White's new blog](http://ericwhite.com/blog), c) [Brian
   Jones & Zeyad Rajabi's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/).
7. Now it's time to start toying around
   with things. You can use the Open
   XML SDK or go commando. The SDK may
   be the best way to start and many
   3rd party tools are based off it.
   [Get the SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0) and dive into the
   the [Word Processing articles
   here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850833.aspx).
8. You can also view How To videos on
   certain subjects. Check out the
   [Open XML "How Do I" Videos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee396255.aspx)
9. Get some tools to help you. The
   [Open XML Package Editor Power Tool
   for Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/450a00e3-5a7d-4776-be2c-8aa8cec2a75b/), [PowerTools for Open XML](http://powertools.codeplex.com/)
   and the
   [Word Content Control Toolkit](http://dbe.codeplex.com/)
   are indispensible.
10. Finally, take a look at what has
    been asked and answered on SO in
    the [openxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openxml), [ooxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ooxml), [openxml-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openxml-sdk),
    [wordprocessingml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordprocessingml) tags.

And there you have it!

Comment: Some of the links above are dead and edit queue is full, so, just updating which link really helped me -> [WordProcessingML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/structure-of-a-wordprocessingml-document)